# Paypal payment script

Tags: php, scripting, paypal, payment

I have a script which enables the users to pay into my paypal account.

Now I need a script which would pay from my account to theirs... I tried to find it but I'm didn't manage... everywhere there are only pay now/cart buttons etc which allows users to pay me, not opposite.

thanks in advance

Comment: Care to share the script that lets them pay you? I've been looking for a simple implementation myself. The [x.com](http://x.com) documentation is sick!

Comment: make a question on stack overflow and post me a link to it.. i will do my best! i know that x.com and paypal.com documentation sux big time... i was playing around with my script over 1 week until I got it exactly as I wanted to

Answer (score 0):

A script that automatically pays from your account to someone else's doesn't, will not ever, exist.
What you can use however, is PayPal Adaptive Chained Payments to automatically transfer part of your funds to a secondary receiver.
Is that what you're looking for?

Have a look at the Adaptive Payments SDK's at https://www.x.com/community/ppx/sdks#ADAPI as well

Comment: What I'm looking for is some solution to speed up payment to multiple receivers as I will have to pay each day to tens of people. Paying to everyone one by one by filling out the form would take ages.

Comment: Tomasz; have a look at the MassPay API in that case; https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_MassPay